# error in the use of useSortable with dnd-kit

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, dnd-kit

I don't know why it gives me an error, the useSortable

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import Cards from "../../components/cards/Cards";
import { Container } from "./HomeStyles";
import {
  DndContext,
  closestCorners,
  MouseSensor,
  TouchSensor,
  useSensor,
  useSensors
} from "@dnd-kit/core";
import {
  arrayMove,
  SortableContext,
  rectSortingStrategy
} from "@dnd-kit/sortable";

const Home = () => {
  const sensors = useSensors(useSensor(MouseSensor), useSensor(TouchSensor));

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: "1",
      text: "H",
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      text: "E",
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      text: "L",
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      text: "L",
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      text: "O",
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <Container>
    <DndContext
      autoScroll={false}
      sensors={sensors}
      collisionDetection={closestCorners}
      onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
    >
      <SortableContext
        items={data.map((i) => i.name)}
        strategy={rectSortingStrategy}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            maxHeight: "30rem",
            maxWidth: "40rem",

            // remove these three lines for a horizontal example
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            flexWrap: "wrap"
          }}
        >
          {data.map((item) => (
            <Cards key={item.id} name={item.text} ids={item.id} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </SortableContext>
    </DndContext>
    </Container>
  );

  function handleDragEnd(event) {
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (active.id !== over.id) {
      setData((items) => {
        const oldIndex = items.findIndex((i) => i.name === active.id);
        const newIndex = items.findIndex((i) => i.name === over.id);

        return arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex);
      });
    }
  }
};

export default Home;
```

and this is my card component

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "./CardsStyled";
import { useSortable } from "@dnd-kit/sortable";
import { CSS } from "@dnd-kit/utilities";

const cards = ({ ids, name }) => {
  const sortable = useSortable({id: ids})
  const {
    attributes,
    listeners,
    setNodeRef,
    transform,
    transition
  } = sortable;

  const style = {
    transition,
    transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform),
    border: "2px solid black",
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Card ref={setNodeRef} {...attributes} {...listeners} style={style}>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default cards;
```

This is the error that I get in the browser

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYiqH.png)

I read in the documentation that the useStortable has to be inside the SortableContext, and what I did was use the useSortable in the same Home and it did not give an error.... But I want to know how it is really used.

Answer (score 1):

You have everything written in error message.

You are importing Card with capital letter:

```
import Cards from "../../components/cards/Cards";
```

and in component it has lower case:

```
const cards = ({ ids, name }) => {
```

Components should start from capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

card component should be in capital letter
for eg:
 instead of

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just capitalize your card component name.
`const cards = ({ ids, name }) => {` should be `const Cards = ({ ids, name }) => {`

In react, all component name should start with capital letter. So to define the card component, you should name it **Cards** instead of **cards**